# Настройка сессии simple membership

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Использую simple membership, и пользователь остается в системе все время, даже если удалить пользователя он все равно залогинен.

Используется стандартный каркас, что генерит VS.

Как это все можно настроить, или в чем проблема?